# MongoDb Mongoose .exec() can not get results to console

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
> cpu.findOne({}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(1).exec(function (err, huh) { 
... if (err) return handleError(err);
... console.log(huh.status);
... console.log("hi");
... })

{ domain: null,
  _events: { err: [Function], complete: [Function] },
  _maxListeners: 10,
  emitted: {},
  ended: false }
```

How do I get the document that is found to be printed to the console in string format? I just get this object instead.

EDIT:

```
> cpu.findOne({}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(1).exec(function (err, result) { console.log(err) })
{ domain: null,
  _events: { err: [Function], complete: [Function] },
  _maxListeners: 10,
  emitted: {},
  ended: false }
>
```

Comment: What does `handleError` do?  Have you verified that the error path isn't called?

Comment: I don't care about `handleError` right now, I got that from mongoose documentation example. I am just trying to get the record to return to the console. it's there...the mongoose record object.

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing what `status` is within the `huh` object.  Also, the output you've pasted above doesn't print the "hi", so it's unclear if there's an error which halts logging prior to that point.

Comment: I believe you're running this from the node console, which I missed previously.  I've had issues with using console logging from there when done in an asynchronous way, as you've done above.  Would you be able to do this from within a script outside of the Node console?

Answer (score 0):

As dylants above has stated, mongoose can not correctly print to the console when ran from the node shell.